# NodeJs, how to return data from co to outside object

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, co

Need help!
How could I get data outside form co ? I don't want to handle them in .then().

I have some code like this (ES6):

```
 static class MyClass{
    //get some data
    static getMyData(){
           co(function *() {
                    //get data by yield, the value is json data
                    let value = yield getSomeData();
                    return value;
         });
    }
}
```

Now I don't want to handle the data in .then(), I just want to get the value out. But if I do this:

```
var result = co(function *(){});
```

What I get is a promise object...

then, how should I get the json data out? thanks.

Comment: why you don't want to get it from `.then()` call?

Answer (score 1):

You can try do this with `yield`, somthing like this:

```
try{    
    var result = yield co(function *(){});
}catch(e){
    console.error(e);
}
```

But i think you must read moar about asynchronous code and i recommend Q promises. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = co.wrap(function* (){
  var list = yield.listNum();
  return list;
})

result(true).then(function(value){
  console.log(value);
})
```

I just get it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getMyData()
    return co(function *() {
        let value = yield getSomeData();
        return Promise.resolve(value);
    });
}

var result = getMyData();
result.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data); // the data is the value variable in function getMyData
})
```